# What is xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier for?

Tags: xcode

After you make global search and replace operation in Xcode it adds `xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier` and `lineEnding` to every manipulated file entry in `*.pbxproj` files in the form of e.g.:

```
036B04CB1B2AE8A70010F649 /* MyClass.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = MyClass.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

to:

```
036B04CB1B2AE8A70010F649 /* MyClass.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; lineEnding = 0; path = MyClass.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier = xcode.lang.objc; };
```

What is it for?

Does it improve something like search performance?

If yes, how can I generate it for other files without making search and replace operation?

If no, how can I prevent Xcode from creating such things?

Comment: Is this happening in projects that were started after Xcode 7 or happening in Xcode 7 on projects that were started before Xcode 7?  Or how about on an individual file level, files created on an older version of Xcode or current?  The implication, of course, being that for stuff created on Xcode 7+, these things already exist, and Xcode only adds them to legacy files as needed.

Comment: No, I have seen this behavior since Xcode 6, and probably even Xcode 5 but I don't remember it very well

Comment: It existed in Xcode 5.  If it is for keyword coloring and completion as explained in @DawnSong's answer, then it likely existed even earlier too.  In my case, global search and replace (within comment blocks) added values of `xcode.lang.objcpp' which makes no sense to me.  Anyone with more info?

Answer (score 2):

I think `xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier` is just a temporary indication from Xcode 6 with Swift's comming; and you can find it in your `project.pbxproj` if you write mixture code with Swift and objc.

For example, you have `ProfileVC.h` and `ProfileVC.m`, then you delete `ProfileVC.h` and rename `ProfileVC.m` to `ProfileVC.swift` (and rewrite it in Swift), in your `projectName.xcodeproject/project.pbxproj`, some line change from

```
    49E89AB31C3D4494006C95BB /* ProfileVC.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = ProfileVC.m; sourceTree = "<group>";};
```

to

```
    49E89AB31C3D4494006C95BB /* ProfileVC.swift */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.swift; lineEnding = 0; path = ProfileVC.swift; sourceTree = "<group>"; xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier = xcode.lang.objc; };
```

However, in this situation, code in ProfileVC.swift seems not correctly colored, and code completion is broken. I delete the part ***xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier = xcode.lang.objc;*** and everything goes quite OK.